# How can I configure SSL for a k6 client using a self-signed certificate on Redhat Linux?

Tags: linux, spring-boot, ssl, redhat, k6

I have tried to follow the documentation and used following code snippet:

```
tlsAuth: [
    {
      domains: ['example.com'],
      cert: open('./mycert.pem'),
      key: open('./mycert-key.pem'),
    }
```

However, I am having difficulty getting this to work. Can you provide some guidance on the necessary steps to configure SSL with a self-signed certificate for a k6 client on Redhat Linux?

Comment: What exactly is "not working"? Do you need the private key? Is any of the files password-protected?